# Bootstrap 5 grid system

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to create a grid system using Bootstrap 5 like below image

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9WDm.png)

I am trying to do grid section like an which i have attached image using bootstrap 5, but it's not working.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: palegreen;">.col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red;">.col-md-6
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: purple;">.col-md-8</div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: aqua;">.col-md-4</div>
            </div>
        </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: you need to have the whole thing inside a `.container` or `.container-fluid` to work

Comment: hi, actually i have added container in my code, here i didn't mentioned

Comment: i have tried right now as you said, but it's not working

Comment: Please crop your image I really don't think you need it that big

Comment: sorry, i will crop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
<style>
        .blue {
            background-color: blue !important;
        }

        .grey {
            background-color: grey;
        }

        .black {
            background-color: black;
        }

        div {
            height: 50px;
        }

        .double {
            height: 100px !important;
        }
    </style>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 black double">
                        A
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 grey">
                        A
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 blue">
                        B
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 blue">
                    A
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 black">
                    B
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 blue">
                    C
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 double">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 grey">
                            A
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 black">
                            B
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 blue">
                            A
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 black double">
                    B
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Really thanks for your contribution. It's perfect. :)

Comment: I am unable to upvote bro otherwise i'll surely upvote your answer. This is the code i wanted. Once again thanks for your time and contribution :)